# Do we live in a post-Meinong-versus-Russell/Quine world?

Tags: metaphysics, reference-request, quine

From a [2022 review](https://ndpr.nd.edu/reviews/non-being-new-essays-on-the-metaphysics-of-non-existence/) of the collection *Non-Being: New Essays on the Metaphysics of Non-existence*:

> This book argues, by omission, that we are in a post-Meinong-versus-Russell/Quine world. This is a welcome shift.

I didn't get the memo that we *do,* assuming that Quine's solution of non-existent objects would still represent the unchallenged mainstream position.

So what changed?

What should one read to get up-to-date?

Comment: Do you agree with the review, as a review of the book in question? Offhand, that book sounds like it would be the up-to-date material you're looking for. The SEP article on [existence](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/existence/) was revised back in 2020, so it's somewhat current. [Nonexistent Objects](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nonexistent-objects/) was updated near the end of last year; [Nothingness](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nothingness/) in February of last year.

Comment: @KristianBerry I don't know if I should agree! It would be interesting where to find the serious knockdown (?) criticism of Quine's approach. Browsing the contents of the mentioned book, it seems it presupposes that already. OTOH, according to the SEP article, Graham Priest would be the first to look at?

Comment: IDK for sure, but maybe it's less an internal knockdown and more a kind of, "Any time we have these intellectual stand-offs, it turns out that progress comes from going beyond both sets of contestants," thing. Like Quine and Meinong both are incomplete?

Comment: The review mentions what changed at the end, "ignoring conservative orthodoxy about existence immediately reveals fruitful directions across many areas and approaches to philosophy". Research after Quine showed that discourse about non-existents leads neither to incoherence nor to lack of parsimony, as he feared. To the contrary, it is productive. So there is no need anymore to twist the language *a la* Russell, or to construct elaborate metaphysical apologies *a la* Meinong to do it. This is how paradigms change in philosophy (and not only), old ones are not refuted, they are abandoned.